# Making a memory game with JavaScript and i need a diferrent way to match cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JS as a project i decided to make a memory game with the function of connecting questions with answers

currently its matching the cards when they share the same image and for my project I need to make pairs of cards with different images

Could anyone give me an alternative to giving values to the cards, I would like to give classes to the cards manually

```
        return card.getElementsByClassName('card-value')[0].src;
```

Comment: Please do not deface your own post. If you no longer need this question, you can delete it (or request that it is deleted by other Users), but removing all the content (known as "Defacing") is not allowed on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy way is to store values/data using data attributes. Here's a quick overview:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes